# Optimizing adding dashes to a long Swift String

Tags: swift, string, optimization

I am trying to take a hex string and insert dashes between every other character (e.g. "b201a968" to "b2-01-a9-68").  I have found several ways to do it, but the problem is my string is fairly large (8066 characters) and the fastest I can get it to work it still takes several seconds.  These are the ways I have tried and how long they are taking. Can anyone help me optimize this function?

```
//42.68 seconds
    func reformatDebugString(string: String) -> String
    {
        var myString = string
        var index = 2
        while(true){
            myString.insert("-", at: myString.index(myString.startIndex, offsetBy: index))
            index += 3
            if(index >= myString.characters.count){
                break
            }
        }

        return myString
    }
```

---

```
//21.65 seconds
    func reformatDebugString3(string: String) -> String
    {
        var myString = ""
        let length = string.characters.count
        var first = true
        for i in 0...length-1{
            let index = string.index(myString.startIndex, offsetBy: i)
            let c = string[index]

            myString += "\(c)"
            if(!first){
                myString += "-"
            }
            first = !first
        }

        return myString
    }
```

---

```
//11.37 seconds
    func reformatDebugString(string: String) -> String
    {
        var myString = string
        var index = myString.characters.count - 2
        while(true){
            myString.insert("-", at: myString.index(myString.startIndex, offsetBy: index))
            index -= 2
            if(index == 0){
                break
            }
        }

        return myString
    }
```

Comment: This seems like a prime use case for parallelization - try dispatch_apply, perhaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already noted in Hamish's answer, you should avoid these two things:

- calculate each index with `string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: ...)`
- modifying a large String with `insert(_:at:)`

So, this can be another way:

```
func reformatDebugString4(string: String) -> String {
    var result = ""

    var currentIndex = string.startIndex
    while currentIndex < string.endIndex {
        let nextIndex = string.index(currentIndex, offsetBy: 2, limitedBy: string.endIndex) ?? string.endIndex
        if currentIndex != string.startIndex {
            result += "-"
        }
        result += string[currentIndex..<nextIndex]
        currentIndex = nextIndex
    }

    return result
}
```

Comment: Good idea to slice the intermediate characters – this is faster than mine (2.08s vs 3.06s in a quick benchmark).

Comment: @Hamish, thanks for evaluation. On my old MacBook, I could not have found significant difference than yours. But the overhead of `enumerated()` can be bigger in some cases, so it's worth trying to avoid it.

Comment: In this case, the use of `enumerated()` actually doesn't appear to have any noticeable effect on the performance – which I would expect, as the compiler should be able to optimise it down to just a simple incrementing value outside of the loop. The speed boost your implementation gets appears to be mainly from the slicing of the intermediate characters (doing two separate appends slows it back down again).

Comment: @Hamish, thanks, I got it. In fact, I could have found some slow downs with _two separate appends_ occasionally (you can guess I have 5, 6, ...), and you explain it.

Comment: @OOper, I have shared my Xcode playground in the link below. On my system my solution is taking about 12.6s, Hamish's is taking 20.5s, and yours is taking about 15.3s. Can you try it on you system? drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz423-2RSnjHMzlGbWNpQy1LSG8

Comment: @RyanTensmeyer, Playground is not a good place to measure performance. Copy all the code into main.swift of macOS Command Line Tool project, and run it.

Comment: @OOPer Thanks for the heads up. Here are the new results. 
Time to evaluate Ryan: 1.717242596 seconds
Time to evaluate Hamish: 0.008418437 seconds
Time to evaluate OOPer: 0.005531507 seconds
It looks like yours is in the lead OOPer

Comment: @RyanTensmeyer, thanks for reporting. But you should know, when executing simple performance tests sequentially, the order affects. And millisecond result can easily be affected by background tasks. When the results are very near, you'd better take average of multiple tests, changing the order.

Comment: @OOPer here are the averages for 1000 iterations where each they were run independent of each other (the first function called in the test) -  Hamish's: 0.008297646856    OOPer's: 0.005797950997

Comment: @RyanTensmeyer, thanks again. Seems mine is actually faster, though it's just a luck as you see in Hamish's comments. Anyway, avoiding repeated O(n) operations is far more significant, which you should have in mind when optimizing your code. May your app be great and fast. Good luck.

Answer (score 9):

The problem with all three of your approaches is the use of `index(_:offsetBy:)` in order to get the index of the current character in your loop. This is an O(n) operation where n is the distance to offset by – therefore making all three of your functions run in quadratic time.

Furthermore, for solutions #1 and #3, your insertion into the resultant string is an O(n) operation, as all the characters after the insertion point have to be shifted up to accommodate the added character. It's generally cheaper to build up the string from scratch in this case, as we can just add a given character onto the end of the string, which is O(1) if the string has enough capacity, O(n) otherwise.

Also for solution #1, saying `myString.characters.count` is an O(n) operation, so not something you want to be doing at each iteration of the loop.

So, we want to build the string from scratch, and avoid indexing and calculating the character count inside the loop. Here's one way of doing that:

```
extension String {

    func addingDashes() -> String {

        var result = ""

        for (offset, character) in characters.enumerated() {

            // don't insert a '-' before the first character,
            // otherwise insert one before every other character.
            if offset != 0 && offset % 2 == 0 {
                result.append("-")
            }

            result.append(character)
        }
        return result
    }
}

// ...

print("b201a968".addingDashes()) // b2-01-a9-68
```

Your best solution (#3) in a release build took 37.79s on my computer, the method above took 0.023s.

Comment: Simple, elegant and fast. EZ PZ.

Comment: @Hamish, I have shared my Xcode playground in the link below.  On my system my solution is taking about 12.6s, yours is taking 20.5s, and OOper's is taking about 15.3s. Can you try it on you system?
 https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz423-2RSnjHMzlGbWNpQy1LSG8

Comment: @RyanTensmeyer Don't use a playground – they're really buggy and unreliable. If you drop the code into an actual project (the macOS command line tool template is a good place to go), you should see the correct results (additionally, it's best to benchmark in a Release build in order to account for compiler optimisations – while also making sure the compiler doesn't completely optimise away the method). [Here's my benchmarking code](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/d1e983e0445084cce314a50333a4d32e).

Comment: @Hamish Thanks for your help. Great solution. I am going to mark OOPer's  solution as the answer as it it slightly faster.

Comment: @RyanTensmeyer Happy to help :)